# hostapd : no such file or directory

Tags: usb, wireless

I'm trying to make my Raspberry work as an access point with a WiFi dongle that has the "Realtek RTL8188CUS" chipset.

I followed the instructions at [blog.sip2serve.com](http://blog.sip2serve.com) and other websites.

My problem: when I try to execute the newly-downloaded `hostapd` binary, it gives me this error:

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/sbin/hostapd: No such file or directory
```

I know this file exists!

The result of `file hostapd`:

```
/usr/sbin/hostapd: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26,    
BuildID[sha1]=0x1b4d974a23f7b58de128fd78ccab6cc105d60766, not stripped
```

and of `file hostapd.bak`:

```
/usr/sbin/hostapd.bak: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, 
BuildID[sha1]=0xda3ab4d3d7f3cac088c8098d94b5cd7fb929ef23, stripped
```

What could be the problem here?

Note: I use the soft float version of Raspbian "wheezy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem,it was because of different version of binary.
the binary I downloaded was for hard-float version,but I used soft-float OS.

I solved it by downloading and installing new hostapd source from jessenger:

http://www.jenssegers.be/blog/43/Realtek-RTL8188-based-access-point-on-Raspberry-Pi

it works fine now.